# remove Builder from classpath

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

In eclipse, if you right click a project you can do the following Project->build path-> configure build path...->Builders

When you see the Builders, you can click one and remove. I am doing eclipse plugin development and was wondering how to accomplish this in the code..? I have the IProject; I just need to get to the list of Builders.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are configured in the `IProjectDescription`, get this with:

```
IProjectDescription desc = project.getDescription();
```

The builders are listed in the build spec:

```
ICommand [] commands = desc.getBuildSpec();
```

You can create a new array adding / removing commands. When you are done update the project description with:

```
desc.setBuildSpec(newCommandArray);
```

You must then update the project description in the project:

```
project.setDescription(desc, null);
```

Comment: nice! thanks! I find these APIs to be a little cumbersome sometime.